# pandas filtering consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I got a Dataframe with a Matrix colum like this

```
11034-A
11034-B
1120-A
1121-A
112570-A
113-A
113.558
113.787-A
113.787-B
114-A
11691-A
11691-B
117-A RRS
12 X R
12-476-AT-A
12-476-AT-B
```

I'd like to filter only matrix that ends with A or B only when they are consecutive, so in the example above 11034-A and 11034-B, 113.787-A and 113.787-B, 11691-A and 11691-B, 12-476-AT-A and 12-476-AT-B

I wrote the function that will compare those 2 strings and return True or False, the problem is I fail to see how to apply / applymap to the consecutive rows:

```
def isAB(stringA, stringB):
    if stringA.endswith('A') and stringB.endswith('B') and stringA[:-1] == stringB[:-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I tried df['result'] = isAB(df['Matrix'].str, df['Matrix'].shift().str) to no-avail
I seem to lack something in the way I designed this

edit :
I think this works, looks like I overcomplicated at 1st :

```
df['t'] = (df['Matrix'].str.endswith('A') & df['Matrix'].shift(-1).str.endswith('B')) | (df['Matrix'].str.endswith('B') & df['Matrix'].shift(1).str.endswith('A'))
df['p'] = (df['Matrix'].str[:-1] == df['Matrix'].shift(-1).str[:-1]) | (df['Matrix'].str[:-1] == df['Matrix'].shift(1).str[:-1])
df['e'] = df['p'] & df['t']

final = df[df['e']]
```

Comment: Your edit is how I would have done it.

Comment: Maybe you can use function %timeit for testing the fastest approach.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I timed my answer along with a lightly modified version of @rurp (I tested if x.Matrix is a string as sometimes it crashed with integer). on average on 100 triies, rurp is 427 long, mine is 80. This doesn't surprise me that .apply is longer. code is here https://gist.github.com/euri10/40ef83fc808415ad3523

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it.

```
df['ShiftUp'] = df['matrix'].shift(-1)
df['ShiftDown'] = df['matrix'].shift()

def check_matrix(x):
    if pd.isnull(x.ShiftUp) == False and x.matrix[:-1] == x.ShiftUp[:-1]:
        return True
    elif pd.isnull(x.ShiftDown) == False and x.matrix[:-1] == x.ShiftDown[:-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['new'] = df.apply(check_matrix, axis=1)
df = df.drop(['ShiftUp', 'ShiftDown'], axis=1)
print df
```

prints

```
         matrix    new
0       11034-A   True
1       11034-B   True
2        1120-A  False
3        1121-A  False
4      112570-A  False
5         113-A  False
6       113.558  False
7     113.787-A   True
8     113.787-B   True
9         114-A  False
10      11691-A   True
11      11691-B   True
12    117-A RRS  False
13       12 X R  False
14  12-476-AT-A   True
15  12-476-AT-B   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, it requires a bit of work.

The strategy is the following: obtain a new column that has the same values as the current column but shifted one position.

Then, it's just a matter to check whether one column is A or B and the other one B or A.

Say your matrix colum is called "column_name".

Then:

```
myl = ['11034-A',
'11034-B',
'1120-A',
'1121-A',
'112570-A',
'113-A',
'113.558',
'113.787-A',
'113.787-B',
'114-A',
'11691-A',
'11691-B',
'117-A RRS',
'12 X R',
'12-476-AT-A',
'12-476-AT-B']

    #toy data frame
    mydf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'column_name':myl})

    #get a new series which is the same one as the original
    #but the first entry contains "nothing"
    new_series = pd.Series(  ['nothing'] + 
    mydf['column_name'][:-1].values.tolist() )

    #add it to the original dataframe
    mydf['new_col'] = new_series
```

You then define a simple function:

```
def do_i_want_this_row(x,y):

    left_char = x[-1]
    right_char = y[-1]
    return ((left_char == 'A') & (right_char == 'B')) or ((left_char == 'B') & (right_char=='A'))
```

and voila:

```
print mydf[mydf.apply(lambda x: do_i_want_this_row( x.column_name, x.new_col), axis=1)]

 column_name      new_col
1       11034-B      11034-A
2        1120-A      11034-B
8     113.787-B    113.787-A
9         114-A    113.787-B
11      11691-B      11691-A
15  12-476-AT-B  12-476-AT-A
```

There is still the question of the last element, but I'm sure you can think of what to do with it if you decide to follow this strategy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete rows from a DataFrame using [`DataFrame.drop(labels, axis)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop). To get a list of labels to delete, I would first get a list of pairs that match your criterion. With the labels from above in a list `labels` and your `isAB` function,

```
pairs = zip(labels[:-1], labels[1:])
delete_pairs = filter(isAB, pairs)

delete_labels = []
for a,b in delete_pairs:
    delete_labels.append(a)
    delete_labels.append(b)
```

Examine`delete_labels` to make sure you've put it together correctly,

```
print(delete_labels)
```

And finally, delete the rows. With the DataFrame in question as `x`,

```
x.drop(delete_labels) # or x.drop(delete_labels, axis) if appropriate
```